# Why is useReducer setup in this way? It feels like it's writing the code backwards?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```js
const initialState = {count: 0};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return {count: state.count + 1};
    case 'decrement':
      return {count: state.count - 1};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Counter() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {state.count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'decrement'})}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'increment'})}>+</button>
    </>
  );
```

This is taken directly from the React documentation.  I want to be specific with this one line of code:

`const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);`

In the newly created variables, state and dispatch we are assigning reducer to dispatch and `initialState` to state.  This seems backward to me.  Why would we declare our state first if `useReducer` is assigning the value from the second parameter of the function (`initialState`).  I hope that I am clear about this question... I know it can be tricky to understand what I am asking.  Basically, why isn't the code setup like this instead?

`const [dispatch, state] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);`

Or:

`const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(initialState, reducer);`

Comment: I think the convention was chosen because of reacts new `useState()` functionality. The first parameter was the returned state, and the second was the setter (In this case the reducer). I think it was to keep similar coding styles.

Comment: because `state` is the result of running the reducer. It is the resultant value that you would use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useReducer` returns an array whose first value is the state and the second value is the dispatch. You are de-structuring these values.

```js
const someArray = () => ['value1','value2']
const [value1 , value2] = someArray()
console.log(value1)
console.log(value2)
```

**As far as why the order is the way it is:**

> `useState` returns an array as `[state, setState]`
>
> `useReducer` returns an array as `[state , dispatch]`
>
> *As you can see both are very similar*

Furthermore: a common theme when calling a function is to pass in the main argument (reducer) as the first argument then its options (initialState). `useReducer(reducer, initialState)`

**Updated Edit Extended Answer:**

This is because you will always pass the main argument and may not pass its options

If useReducer required you to call it with `useReducer(initialValues, reducer)` you wouldn't be able to call it without initalValues such as `useReducer(reducer)` as useReducer would then think that reducer was your initalValues and that no reducer was passed in.

React Team could have instead chose to accept an object such as `{initalValues, reducer}` and order would not matter but that is not the case

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'm a relatively novice programmer especially within redux.  My follow up question to this is: aren't callback functions also listed second ( or later) within function params as well?  I haven't seen many instances yet of having a function as a first parameter but that could just be due to experience level.

Comment: I updated my answer with a deeper explanation but yes there are times when you want your callback function to be the first arg (such as when the number of args varies)

Comment: Thanks for the help!